# How to search for String that has more than one word in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

My search method works fine for one word strings, but not for two words or more.

I am supposed to check to see if the titleToFind matches a DVD title in the

```
ArrayList<DVD>DVDlist
```

My search method:

```
public DVD search(String titleToFind) {
    for (DVD dvdEntry : DVDlist) {
        if (dvdEntry.GetTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(titleToFind)) {
            return dvdEntry;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase`doesn't care about how many words your strings are. if they're equal, they're equal. Maybe you're looking for `contains` instead?

Comment: One way would be to save the found titles in another ArrayList and return this.

Comment: I agree with NilsH. If you're unable to locate Strings that contain more than one word then the problem isn't with your search function but with something else and we'd need to see more code with example inputs/results.

Comment: Based on the answers, there's some confusion. Is the problem that you can't get more than one result from the search, or that your search does not match anything when you use more than one word?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, could you gave us an example of the strings that don't work?

Comment: @AlexMusk, I added in the 'contains' and that helped a little with my other problem, which I didn't mention. But if I searched for "choo choo", it doesn't bring up the DVD pieces. But it does if I capitalized those words.

Comment: Works fine for me.... http://pastebin.com/0ZyQetSN

Comment: Can you try adding: `inputFile.useDelimiter
         (System.getProperty("line.separator"));` after `new Scanner ...` line?

Comment: i cant find any problems, your code works fine for me. it finds both "choo choo" and "Choo Choo" along with any other variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you stop searching when you hit your first match (the return statement in the loop).  Below is an example of returning a list containing all the matches.

If you are not allowed to use a list, you could return an int (number of matches) or csv of matches.

```
public List<DVD> search(String titleToFind) {
    List<DVD> matches = new ArrayList<DVD>();    
    for (DVD dvdEntry : DVDlist) {
        if (dvdEntry.GetTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(titleToFind)) {
            matches.add(dvdEntry);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Comment: I don't I am allowed to use another ArrayList

Comment: @trama : Could you explain why you are not allowed ?